# Open/Read Document Drive API

Tags: android, google-drive-api

i'm currently making an app that can read and possibly edit document file via android. the files.list API is already work, so i can read drive content from any google account. the question is how to open all those file? 

is there any API to read the file content, or should i download the file first and then open it with corresponding app in my phone? which way better actually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use the API to download the file. See the examples for the [`files.get` method](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/get).